# Php mysqli how to return changing db variables?

Tags: php, database, select, mysqli, fetch

I am trying to query a database to check if a user owns an item or not. Suppose the $username is bob and the $databaseVar is greenJacket. The value of green jacket in the database cell is either a 1 for owns or 0 for doesn't own. However, when I call the last line, return $result->$databaseVar, it always will return "greenJacket", the name of the database variable. This is bad because what I wanted what the value of the database variable. I have tried many things and can't figure it out. Any help?

```
 public function checkIfItemOwned($username, $databaseVar)
{

    $query = $this->connection->query("SELECT '$databaseVar' FROM items WHERE name='$username';");

    if ($result = $query->fetch_object())
    {

        return $result->$databaseVar;

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: In the example you gave, "greenJacket" *is* the value of `$databaseVar`, by the way you set up the question...

Comment: Why am i getting down votes for this? Very tricky problem.

Answer (score 2):

The correct SQL syntax should be: (note ``` `` ``` and `''` symbols)

```
SELECT `$databaseVar` FROM items WHERE name='$username';
```

Otherwise, you just select the string value of `$databaseVar`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Changing ' to ` made all the difference.